# ItemsControl and GroupStyle issues

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, groupstyle

The following code generates a UserControl for every item in a collection. The data is displayed correctly, but for some reasons which I can't understand, all the UserControls have the same size.

[image: See picture]

As you can see, Group2 contains multiple StackPanels. All these StackPanels have the very same dimensions and is not resizing according to the content.

Any idea why? Is it because of the StackPanel defined in the ItemsPanelTemplate?

```
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="test" Source="{Binding}">
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Column"/>
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource> 

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource test}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <controls:Template/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle.Panel>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: did you set a fixed height on your custom usercontrol?

Comment: No. The actual dimension of each usercontrol is fine (they are behind the "actual content" label in the picture). It is just the stackpanel.

Comment: when i replace your usercontrol with a simple border with height="50", the stackpanel does not take more than what he needs for the content, so i kind of think your usercontrol is demanding that height. does using a simple border with 50 height and 50 width still take full height with your code?

Comment: I understand. But in your test, all the stackpanels will have the same identical size because the content (the usercontrol) is always the same. Perhaps it wasn’t clear enough, but that usercontrol contains other dynamic content so its size is not the same for all the instances: this leads to stackpanels having different sizes (in theory) but for some reason they all have a fixed size, which is the biggest of all the stackpanels.